# No location header inside success callback for jasmine mocked ajax call

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-ajax

I am mocking an ajax request using jasmine-ajax as follows

```
jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
    "status": 200,
    "responseText": '{}'
});
```

I am trying to get the 'Location' header for the request object passed to the ajax success callback as follows:

```
success(function(data, textStatus, request) {
    var url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
    url = url.substring(...);
}
```

but it returns null and the jasmine test fails because substring function is called on null. What should I do?
Note: I can access the 'Location' header just fine if the ajax request is not mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could add that function to the object that you are returning:

```
jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
  "status": 200,
  "responseText": '{}',
  "getResponseHeader": function(arg) { return 'customlocation';}
});
```